# AJAX renaming <div> text

Tags: ajax, html

I want to rename the content of a  tag without opening a specific file. In this code I am basing it reads the contents of test.txt which replaces the text inside  tag.

I want to modify this code in a way that it will not need to open any text file and I could set the text manually within the code itself. Is this possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button id="test" type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Expand</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean static content? if yes, just use `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='some text';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set static text inside the div without open a file, the code below works well. Of course, this isn't AJAX anymore, just JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var previousContent;

function changeDivText(){
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var test = document.getElementById("test");

    if (test.innerHTML == "Expand"){
        previousContent = myDiv.innerHTML
        myDiv.innerHTML = "static text";
        test.innerHTML = "Reduce";
    }
    else{
        myDiv.innerHTML = previousContent;
        test.innerHTML = "Expand";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button id="test" type="button" onclick="changeDivText()">Expand</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes this works thanks alot, but I want to add something.. a function that changes the name of my button from Expand to Reduce vice versa when i click it and it also reverts from the old <div> content to the replaced <div> content vice versa same process with the button. Is that possible?

Comment: I've edited the code. I suggest you to learn the JavaScript basics, it's very cool!

Comment: Thanks alot man. i've been rolling on the floor for minutes now. My day is now complete.

Comment: I have a problem. wordpress does not support javascript. is there a way i can make it support javascript?

Comment: Man, Wordpress only generates dynamic HTML. It should be another problem.